# How to check if an Android activity is using WebView

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I have a situation where I need to inspect an app for which I only have the APK. When I run the app, I am interested in inspecting a specific Activity. I know the particular Activity being used by using the following command:

```
 adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger
```

From the above I can see all the layers, and can tell which Activity the app is currently running. The question I want to answer next is whether this Activity is using a Webview.

Is there any tool available or any command in adb that can achieve this ?

I did try to use `dex2jar` and `apktool` to try to find that Activity, but reading decompiled / disassembled code does help me make an accurate conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `uiautomatorviewer`. Or, if the app is debuggable, use Android Studio's Layout Inspector.

Comment: Knowing which activity is being used, is it also possible to find out which layout file is being used by the activity ?

Comment: @Jake: Not readily. After all, an activity can use zero, one, or several layout resources while constructing its UI.